# Apply configuration to base class without creating a table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am making an application, following the principles of Entity Framework code first, using the [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) feature.

To avoid having the same code in every class, I have made a base class called `AuditableEntity` which contains the basic properties that all (auditable) entities must contain:

```
public abstract class AuditableEntity
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDtm { get; private set; }
}
```

Now the field `CreatedBy` should have a default SQL value of `CURRENT_USER`.

And the field `CreatedDtm` should have a default SQL value of `GETDATE()`.

Normally I would make a configuration file for the table, in which this is done, like this:

```
public class AuditableEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AuditableEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AuditableEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasDefaultValueSql("USER_NAME()");
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedDtm).HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");
    }
}
```

But if I do this, Entity Framework wants to create a table called `AuditableEntity`. This is (obviously) not my intention. I want `AuditableEntity` to be an abstract base, not an actual entity. Or in other words, I want it to provide some very basic shared functionality for my actual entities.

Is there any way I can do something similar, which allows all classes inheriting from `AuditableEntity` to get the default SQL values described above?

I would like it done in a way, so that the logic applies on database level, so it is not as simple as setting the values in the C# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic class, that will avoid to create a config class for each type but you will need to register the config for each type:

```
public class AuditableEntityConfiguration<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : AuditableEntity
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasDefaultValueSql("USER_NAME()");
        builder.Property(e => e.CreatedDtm).HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()");
    }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AuditableEntityConfiguration<DerivedClass1>());
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AuditableEntityConfiguration<DerivedClass2>());
}
```

If speed is not important then you can always use reflection to get all types that derive from AuditableEntity and register the configurations dynamically.